# How to get activity reference using package context in Android

Tags: android

My application launches third party app and I have to get package context for that app. I have an activity class name. Now i want to get the activity reference/context using the package context and activity class name.

How can I do this?

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 0):

To get your launcher activity use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)

```
getLaunchIntentForPackage
```

On this Intent call `getComponentName` and from the returned `CompomemtName` call `getClassName`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
String className = launchIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
```